# "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" in Vite+React app. Error in path-parse module in node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite

I have a Vite based React App.
I get the following error when I run 'npm run dev':

Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined     at node_modules/path-parse/index.js (index.js:3:17)

Problem is here in node_modules/path-parse/index.js ->
 `var isWindows = process.platform === 'win32';`

path-parse is at the latest - 1.0.7.

There has to be some config in vite to avoid this error [Source : [https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1973#issuecomment-787571499\]](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1973#issuecomment-787571499%5C%5D).

So I tried:
`import { defineConfig } from 'vite' export default defineConfig({ // ...     define: {     'process.env': {}     } })`
But that gave me other errors on node not being able to find the current version of Node.
I am expecting that there is no error when accessing the `process.platform`.

So please help me solve this error.

Comment: Do you use any other libraries except react?

Comment: @Konrad 
**dependencies:** feather-icons, framer-motion, react-dom, react-scripts, react-slick, slick-carousel, styled-components, twin.macro, vite-plugin-svgr
**devDependencies:** @types/react,@types/react-dom, @vitejs/plugin-react, eslint, eslint-plugin-react, eslint-plugin-react-hooks, eslint-plugin-react-refresh, vite

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to use the [treact](https://treact.owaiskhan.me/) UI components.

So I had the same errors, the only thing that helped me was this [article](https://blog.devgenius.io/react-vite-tailwind-css-twin-macro-storybook-svg-imports-as-react-component-6b44d5e2641)

go through it carefully. hope it helps!

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with 'mime-types'.
I resolved the process.env issue, but still facing the process error because of a dependency I'm using-"mime-types" it's using process.platform in the same way you mentioned. Here's the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at node_modules/path/path.js (path.js:25:17)
at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=58336a29:18:50)
at node_modules/mime-types/index.js (index.js:16:15)
```

in this line:

```
var isWindows = process.platform === 'win32';
```

I looked at the article link here and many other articles, discussions, and issues, and all I got is a workaround:

```
define: { 
    'process.env': {}, // to workaround the process.env error but not a 
                       //permanent fix  
    },
```

but it still causes issues with the production build, there now the error throws:
`process is undefined`

but this works great(after build too!):

```
define: {
'process.platform': JSON.stringify(process.platform),
```

},

it's also a workaround but it works for both the development environment as well as production builds, I'll eventually switch to a better/latest library with browser environment compatibility soon but this works for now.

here's a link to check out why it happened to me:https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/issues/214#issuecomment-1695735861